# Perl system() command failing after fork

Tags: perl, system, fork, parallel-processing

I have a perl script which calls fork() a few times to create 4 child processes.  The parent process then uses waitpid() to wait for all of the children to finish.

The problem occurs when I try to call system() from within the child processes (I'm using it to create directories).  Even something as simple as system("dir") fails (yes, I'm on Windows).

By "fails", I mean that one of the child threads goes past it no problem, but the other child processes so far as I can tell simply cease to exist.

```
trace INFO, "Thread $thread_id still alive at 2.62";
system("dir");
trace INFO, "Thread $thread_id still alive at 2.65";
```

I get messages such as "Thread 3 still alive at 2.62", but only 1 of the child threads ever gets to 2.65.

At the bottom of the log, I can see "Command exited with non-zero status 127", which I think may have something to do with it.

I've considered using some sort of a mutex lock to make sure that only 1 processes at a time goes through the system calls, but how can I do that with fork()?  Also, this problem doesn't really make any sense in the first place, why would several independent processes have trouble doing system("dir") at the same time?

Comment: Why are you using `system()` to create directories?

Comment: What version of perl are you using? Is it thread-safe?

Comment: Could you provide (a minimal amount of) code that reproduces the problem for us to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that [`fork()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html) is emulated under windows using threads. So there is no real processes created.

If you are *only* use system call to create folders, then you'd better use perl function [`mkdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html) or [File::Path](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aPath)'s `make_path` instead.

Comment: Each of the threads is running on it's own CPU Core though, is this relevant?  (I have a quad core CPU and running 4 threads makes it go to 100%, as opposed to 25% without parallelization)

Comment: Threads are sharing memory. Probably `system` requires exclusive access to some internal structure (but it's shared, because no new *process* is created)

Comment: @Ivan Nevostruev, It's not clear to me what you're saying, but if you're saying that `system` doesn't create a new process, that's wrong.

Comment: @ikegami I'm not quite sure how perl `system` works under windows. But at some point it'll call WinAPI. It looks like WinAPI, perl calling, is not thread safe. That's why I've asked for version of perl used by OP.

Comment: I'm using Perl v5.12.4.  Using mkdir instead of system appears to be working fine.  Not sure why system was used in the first place, it wasn't my code to begin with.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for `File::Path` link